UNPIVOT from the output of Temp Local Table
I have the following SQL where I'm trying to UNPIVOT the result from the temp local table #tempTbl_tblF0902
SELECT 
   [JDE Fiscal Year], [Business Unit], [Cost Code], [Cost Description], [Cost with Description], [Trade Code], [Trade Description], [Trade with Description],
   [Periods], [Postings]
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM #tempTbl_tblF0902
) as pvt

UNPIVOT
(
   [Postings] FOR [Periods] IN ([Balance Forward],[Net Posting 01], [Net Posting 02], [Net Posting 03], [Net Posting 04], [Net Posting 05], [Net Posting 06], [Net Posting 07], [Net Posting 08], [Net Posting 09], [Net Posting 10], [Net Posting 11], [Net Posting 12] )
)

DROP TABLE #tempTbl_tblF0902

However, I get the red squiggly line in my [Periods], [Postings] and DROP
When I try to execute the script, I was given an error where it says

Invalid column name 'Periods'

and

Invalid column name 'Postings'

What did I do wrong here and how should it be fix?
Thank you in advanced

Found my error.
Need to give an alias after my close bracket of UNPIVOT
UNPIVOT
(
   [Postings] FOR [Periods] IN ([Balance Forward],[Net Posting 01], [Net Posting 02], [Net Posting 03], [Net Posting 04], [Net Posting 05], [Net Posting 06], [Net Posting 07], [Net Posting 08], [Net Posting 09], [Net Posting 10], [Net Posting 11], [Net Posting 12] )
) as unpvt

